# Remove space from exported filename in R using xlsx package

Tags: r, naming-conventions, naming, r-xlsx

Trying to export a file using write.xlsx() from package "xlsx".

File export works as expected, however having trouble with the naming convention.

I wish for the file to be names as follows:

```
filename <today's date>.xlsx
```

At present I can do either of the following:

```
write.xlsx(exports, paste("filename", Sys.Date(),".xlsx"))

which gives:

filename 2020-04-21 .xlsx
```

Or I can write

```
write.xlsx(exports, paste("filename", Sys.Date(),".xlsx", sep = ""))

which gives:

filename2020-04-21.xlsx
```

How do I remove the space between the date and file extension such that the file name is:

```
filename 2020-04-01.xlsx
```

I appreciate this is somewhat a vanity thing and I could use `sep = "_"` to place underscores throughout, but this is not the naming convention I am trying to achieve.

Comment: `"filename "` in the last example. If it's an actual variable just add another paste, `paste(filename, Sys.Date())` there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow. I cannot believe I didn't think to just add an additional space in the last example.

Going to blame cabin fever from social distancing/isolating for that little derp.

```
write.xlsx(exports, paste("filename ", Sys.Date(),".xlsx", sep = ""))
```